# coroutineScope start first than launch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm studying coroutine,
and writing some examples, I found some weird things.
even if I write the `launch` build first,
it start late than coroutineScope.
I understand coroutineScope has a suspending point.
Is there any one who explain this?

below is my code

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {

    launch {
        println("Start")
    }

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("World!")
        }

        println("Hello")
    }

    println("Done")

/*    
    expected

    Start
    Hello
    World!
    Done
    
    result

    Hello
    Start
    World!
    Done
 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`launch` block isn't executed immediately. It is sort of scheduled for asynchronous execution and the function returns immediately. That's why "Start" is not printed immediately and the control moves inside the `coroutineScope`. You can verify this with a simple example like:

```kotlin
launch {
    println("Start")
}
println("End")
```

Here you will see that `End` is printed before `Start`

Comment: thank u for your answer. I want to understand the difference between launch and coroutineScope. because the `launch` is not executed but the `coroutineScope` is executed immediately. Is the coroutineScope like preemptive message?

Comment: `launch` is for starting a coroutine. `coroutineScope` creates a scope from which you can launch children coroutines in parallel and wait for them to finish. There’s nothing preemptive. It just isn’t launching a new coroutine. You might be confused because you’re doing this from within a `runBlocking`  You’re already in a coroutine. `launch` can be called from anywhere, not just inside a coroutine, so long as you have a CoroutineScope to call it on. `coroutineScope` can only be called from inside a coroutine and it runs immediately. There is nothing really comparable between the two.